# Empty attributes displaying as No - I've rewritten the block and it still displays No

Tags: magento-1.9, product-attribute

I have rewritten the Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View_Attributes block with the following to not display N/A or No attributes. However, some blank attributes are still displaying as No on the front end. I want to be able to keep Yes/No type attributes on the front end so I can't just apply an if statement for "No". Is there somewhere else Magento could be changing an empty attribute to No?

EDIT: After further research it appears this is happening on dropdown attributes.

```
public function getAdditionalData(array $excludeAttr = array())
{
    $data = array();
    $product = $this->getProduct();
    $attributes = $product->getAttributes();
    foreach ($attributes as $attribute) {
//            if ($attribute->getIsVisibleOnFront() && $attribute->getIsUserDefined() && !in_array($attribute->getAttributeCode(), $excludeAttr)) {
        if ($attribute->getIsVisibleOnFront() && !in_array($attribute->getAttributeCode(), $excludeAttr)) {
            $value = $attribute->getFrontend()->getValue($product);

            if (!$product->hasData($attribute->getAttributeCode())) {
                $value = Mage::helper('catalog')->__('N/A');
            } elseif ((string)$value == '') {
                // $value = Mage::helper('catalog')->__('No');
            } elseif ($attribute->getFrontendInput() == 'price' && is_string($value)) {
                $value = Mage::app()->getStore()->convertPrice($value, true);
            }
            if($value === 'N/A' || $value === ''){
                //do nothing makes sure N/A and empty attributes don't show up on product view page
            }
            elseif(is_string($value) && strlen($value)) {
                $data[$attribute->getAttributeCode()] = array(
                    'label' => $attribute->getStoreLabel(),
                    'value' => $value,
                    'code'  => $attribute->getAttributeCode()
                );
            }


        }
    }
    return $data;
}
```

Comment: did you try import with empty cells?

Answer (score 1):

Hide the empty attributes by just edit the template file named as app/design/frontend/[mypackage]/[mytheme]/template/catalog/product/view/attributes.phtml

**In your code, find following lines:**

```
<?php foreach ($_additional as $_data): ?>
     <tr>
         <th class="label"><?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->__($_data['label'])) ?></th>
         <td class="data"><?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_data['value'], $_data['code']) ?></td>
     </tr>
```

**Replace this:**

```
<?php foreach ($_additional as $_data): ?>
   <?php if ((string)$_data['value'] != '' and $_data['value'] != 'N/A'): ?>
   <tr>
        <th class="label"><?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->__($_data['label'])) ?></th>
        <td class="data"><?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_data['value'], $_data['code']) ?></td>
    </tr>
  <?php endif; ?>
  <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: This is simply a way to hide the attributes, I want to avoid the slight performance hit by changing the block. Also, if you look at the block any '' value is changed to 'No' before it's sent to the template file so this won't weed out any blank attributes.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue. It seems Magento sets the value to "no" when you dont select anything in a dropdown. So my solution is:

```
if($value === 'N/A' || $value === '' || $value === 'nein'){
            //do nothing makes sure N/A and empty attributes don't show up on product view page
        }
            elseif (is_string($value) && strlen($value)) {
                $data[$attribute->getAttributeCode()] = array(
                    'label' => $attribute->getStoreLabel(),
                    'value' => $value,
                    'code'  => $attribute->getAttributeCode()
                );
            }
```

Had to use "nein" because I have a german site and Magento seems to use the translated value at this point.

But whats bothers me is: What do you do when the value should be no?

EDIT:
Thats my solution by now:

```
public function getAdditionalData(array $excludeAttr = array())
{
    $data = array();
    $product = $this->getProduct();
    $attributes = $product->getAttributes();
    foreach ($attributes as $attribute) {

        if ($attribute->getIsVisibleOnFront() && !in_array($attribute->getAttributeCode(), $excludeAttr)) {
            $value = $attribute->getFrontend()->getValue($product);

            if (!$product->hasData($attribute->getAttributeCode()) 
                || (string)$value == '' 
                || ($attribute->getFrontendInput() == 'select' && $product->getAttributeText((string)$attribute->getAttributeCode()) == '') ) {

                $value = Mage::helper('catalog')->__('N/A');
            } elseif ($attribute->getFrontendInput() == 'price' && is_string($value)) {
                $value = Mage::app()->getStore()->convertPrice($value, true);
            }

            if($value === Mage::helper('catalog')->__('N/A') || $value === ''){

            }
            elseif (is_string($value) && strlen($value)) {
                $data[$attribute->getAttributeCode()] = array(
                    'label' => $attribute->getStoreLabel(),
                    'value' => $value,
                    'code'  => $attribute->getAttributeCode()
                );
            }
        }
    }
    return $data;
}
```